# Why does DB2 CHAR() function return '24:00:00' for a time field that is 00:00:00?

Tags: select, time, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm querying DB2 on i (AS/400).  A plain SELECT statement on a column with datatype of TIME returns 00:00:00, but when I use the CHAR() function it returns '24:00:00'.

I understand that 24:00:00 is a valid time, but why would CHAR() return 24 when the native TIME returs 00?

Comment: I've got over 10 million records with a TIME value of 00:00:00, but only one of them returns '24:00:00' when CHAR() is used.

Answer (score 0):

On V5R4:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (FIELD1 TIME NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT)

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('00:00:00')

SELECT FIELD1, CHAR(FIELD1) FROM TEST
```

Shows:

```
FIELD1    CHAR ( FIELD1 ) 
00:00:00     00:00:00
```

Not sure why you are getting 24:00:00.

I also tried:

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('24:00:00')
```

thinking maybe a 24:00:00 value was displaying as '00:00:00' but this shows:

```
FIELD1    CHAR ( FIELD1 ) 
00:00:00     00:00:00     
24:00:00     24:00:00
```

for pretty much all Time formats (*HMS, ISO).